# Using filestream.seek method with a device

Tags: c#, device, filestream

I'm using filestream.seek method with a filestream created for a device, so using a filehandle instead of a filename and it seems that it only moves the reading pointer at a sector level. So no way to go forward or backward 3 bytes or 12 bytes, it goes 512 bytes.

Does anyone know if this is the normal way it works or probably i'm doing something wrong?

So many thanks .

Comment: Yes, the ability to seek to an arbitrary offset on a block-structured device (like a disk) is provided by the file system cache.  My crystal ball says that you don't actually like the FileOptions.WriteThrough option.  Nobody does.

Comment: @HansPassant I have exactly the same issue but I was unable to parse your comment as successfully as Carlos... Isn't FileOptions used only when creating the stream through File.Create? I want to create it directly from a safe file handle to the device. Resulting stream not seekable...